# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 using join with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, join

I have two tables and I am trying to `join` them in order to get all the referenced tables but getting errors but I am not sure which part I am doing wrong, can someone please give me a hand?

I have this table migration for tickets

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('ticketNumber')->nullable(true)->unique();
        $table->boolean('is_deleted')->default(false);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I have this table which saves notes for the tickets `ticket_notes` and I am referencing using the `ticketNumber` instead of the `id`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    Schema::create('ticket_notes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('ticketNumber');
        $table->foreign('ticketNumber')->references('ticketNumber')->on('tickets');
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('rloc', 50);
        $table->boolean('is_deleted')->default(false);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I am usin `query builder` to do the query instead of `eloquent relationships`

```
DB::table('tickets')->where([
    'ticketNumber' => 12345,
    'is_deleted'   => false,
])
    ->join('ticket_notes', 'tickets.ticketNumber', '=', 'ticket_notes.ticketNumber')
    ->select('tickets.*');
```

I am getting this error
`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'ticketNumber' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select`tickets`.* from`tickets`inner join`ticket_notes`on`tickets`.`ticketNumber`=`ticket_notes`.`ticketNumber`where (`ticketNumber`= 12345 and`is_deleted`= 0))`

Anyone can give me a fresh look where I did wrong with the join?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions / help.

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the join, there are 2 columns named ticketNumber. Specify which one you want.
`'tickets.ticketNumber' => 12345`

```
DB::table('tickets')->where([
    'tickets.ticketNumber' => 12345,
    'is_deleted'   => false,
])
->join('ticket_notes', 'tickets.ticketNumber', '=', 
    'ticket_notes.ticketNumber')
->select('tickets.*');
```

Comment: ah! thx thx, do really need the fresh eye. I know this isn't in the question and your answer solved it.  But just another quick question if you are able to give me a hand.  I realized after querying this gives me two arrays if there are two notes.  Is it possible to combine them and return one object and having the notes as an array instead?

Comment: @Dora Please ask further questions in new posts, not comments.